# Getting Badge value dynamically in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am working on a chat widget where I need to get the count of "addResponseMessage" which is responsible to display bot messages in the frontend, so that I can pass that count to badge to display it dynamically, I tried so many methods but nothing worked

I am new to react and struggling in this for 2 days.

Comment: Where do you store the count variable ? Probably you should keep it in your state and set when it changes with `this.setState({ count: someValue })`, hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it, still I am unable to understand. It will be really very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make count a state property.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component
{
   constructor(props)
   {
      state = {
        count:0
      }
   }
}
```

now when you need to update count instead of `this.count++` do

```js
this.setState((old_state)=>{
    let new_count = ++old_state.count;
    return { count: new_count }

})
```

inside render function replace `this.count` to `this.state.count`.

and also have a look in react documentation it's neat and easy to understand